# CSS transition not working for height: 0 (but for other heights)

Tags: css, css-transitions

I would like the transition to work when the header is going hidden as well. But it disappears immediately. Please look at the code and scroll down to see the effect:

```js
function getScrollTop() {
    return window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
}

function showHeaderHidden() {
    document.getElementById('header').classList.add('hidden');
    document.getElementById('header').classList.remove('fixed');
}

function showHeaderFixed() {
    document.getElementById('header').classList.add('fixed');
    document.getElementById('header').classList.remove('hidden');
}

function showHeaderFull() {
    document.getElementById('header').classList.remove('fixed');
    document.getElementById('header').classList.remove('hidden'); 
}

var lastScrollTop = 0;

function atPageTop(scroll) {
    return scroll < 1;
}

function scrollingDown(scroll) {
    return scroll > lastScrollTop
}

function onWindowScroll() {
    var scrollTop = getScrollTop();
    
    if (scrollingDown(scrollTop)) {
        if (scrollTop > 300) {
            showHeaderHidden();
        } else {
            showHeaderFixed();
        }
    } else {
        if (atPageTop(scrollTop)) {
            showHeaderFull();
        } else {
            showHeaderFixed();
        }
    }
    
    lastScrollTop = scrollTop;
}

lastScrollTop = getScrollTop();

window.onscroll = function () {
  onWindowScroll();
};
```

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
  margin: 0px;
}

header {
  height: 120px;
  background: red;
  
  transition: .5s;
}

header.fixed {
  position: fixed;
 z-index: 10;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 45px;
  background: green;
  
  transition: .5s;
}

header.hidden {
  height: 0px;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  
</header>
```

As you can see I specified a transition, but it is ignored for some reason:

```
header.hidden {
  height: 0px;

  transition: .5s;
}
```

Hope someone can help me!

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Please don't post your code to 3rd party sites as those links can die over time and then your question is meaningless to those who come across it. Instead, include your code, right here in your question in a "code snippet".

Comment: @ScottMarcus Thank you, I didn't realize how to do it properly. I appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are removing the `fixed` class in the second step which create the issue as your element will get back its initial position. You should keep this class with `hidden`:

```js
function getScrollTop() {
  return window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
}

function showHeaderHidden() {
  document.getElementById('header').classList.add('hidden');
  /* document.getElementById('header').classList.remove('fixed'); remove this*/
}

function showHeaderFixed() {
  document.getElementById('header').classList.add('fixed');
  document.getElementById('header').classList.remove('hidden');
}

function showHeaderFull() {
  document.getElementById('header').classList.remove('fixed');
  document.getElementById('header').classList.remove('hidden');
}

var lastScrollTop = 0;

function atPageTop(scroll) {
  return scroll < 1;
}

function scrollingDown(scroll) {
  return scroll > lastScrollTop
}

function onWindowScroll() {
  var scrollTop = getScrollTop();

  if (scrollingDown(scrollTop)) {
    if (scrollTop > 300) {
      showHeaderHidden();
    } else {
      showHeaderFixed();
    }
  } else {
    if (atPageTop(scrollTop)) {
      showHeaderFull();
    } else {
      showHeaderFixed();
    }
  }

  lastScrollTop = scrollTop;
}

lastScrollTop = getScrollTop();

window.onscroll = function() {
  onWindowScroll();
};
```

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
  margin: 0px;
}

header {
  height: 120px;
  background: red;
  transition: .5s;
}

header.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 45px;
  background: green;
  /*transition: .5s; can be removed */
}

header.hidden {
  height: 0px;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">

</header>
```

Comment: I think I understand... the transition *is* happening, but at the top of the page? Thanks a lot, I missed that!

Comment: @smoothware exactly ;) it's happening at the initial place without the fixed position